# How to convert .txt file in resx to list<string>

Tags: c#, wpf

so  far:

```
List<string> names = Properties.Resources.first_names.ToArray().ToList();
```

produce wrong result,

the txt is like=> `"Shirley","Rose","Sean","Jeremy"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read embedded resource text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Comment: not about embedding its about converting to list<string> @X-TECH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex to split on the commas outside of the quotes like so:

```
var names = Regex.Split(Properties.Resources.first_names, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

Then loop over each entry and remove the quotes like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
{
    names[i] = names[i]Replace("\"", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read text file contents from resources and convert to list, try this:

```
byte[] file = Properties.Resources.myResourceFile;
string text;
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(file))
{
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
     {
          text = reader.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
var names = text.Split(',').ToList();
```